# Advanced Logging missing from IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis, iis-8

I have just installed the features in IIS 8 for Health and Diagnostics in order to enable Advanced Logging in IIS. There should be an Advanced Logging icon that appears in IIS Manager, but there is none. Other logging features I added such as Enabled Failed Request Tracing are working without any problems.

Also, I checked in %windir%\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema for evidence of an Advanced Logging schema, but there is none.

Any suggestions for how I can get this running?

Comment: I'd like to see a screen shot of that.... Upload somewhere and then send a link to image.

Comment: I've posted images from the server and the site at [server link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/146949995@N05/29469158276/in/dateposted-public/) and at [site link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/146949995@N05/28878458864/in/dateposted-public/)

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT that link seems to apply to Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, and Windows Vista. I am looking to run this on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS Advanced Logging is an out of band module. You must install it using Web Publishing Installer or you can download it [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging).

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7211 this is the direct link

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Logging for older IIS systems is no longer supported and the link is officially dead from Microsoft. Get it from the Internet Archive instead (thankfully they have a mirror of the download still).

https://web.archive.org/web/20200803164258/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7211